# iOS: Localised UIButton With Image and Title Label With Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm wonder is there a way to make a button that includes UIImage and title label under the image using auto layout. I made this using title insets left with negative value. But, right now I want to add localisation to my app and, of course, title labels of my buttons won't be a constant value. I see the only way: calculate every insets for every button for a particular text (for every localisation). This is quite annoying.

Is there a way to replace insets with auto layout **without** separation of UIButton?